# how can I get the result from second code?

Tags: php, ajax

I have modified my question. How can I get the result from second form? because I have create two form with similar code, however I can only get the result from the first form and when I press the second one, it still get the result from first form. Can someone help me out?

Code

```
<div>
<form id="fupForm" name="form1" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="gp_name" name="gp_name" 
value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<? 
php 
echo $deday;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" 
value="Hotel">
</div>
<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" 
 value="Add Hotel" id="butsave">
</form></div>

<div>
<form id="fupForm2" name="form2" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="gp_name" name="gp_name" 
value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<? 
php 
echo $deday;?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" 
value="Coach">
</div>
<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" 
 value="Add Coach" id="butsave2">
</form></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butsave').on('click', function() {
    $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    if(gp_name!="" && date!="" && type!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                gp_name: gp_name,
                date: date,
                type: type              
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                    $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
                    $("#success").show();
                    $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                }
                else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                   alert("Error occured !");
                }

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert('Please fill all the field !');
    }
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butsave2').on('click', function() {
    $("#butsave2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    if(gp_name!="" && date!="" && type!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                gp_name: gp_name,
                date: date,
                type: type              
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                    $("#butsave2").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#fupForm2').find('input:text').val('');
                    $("#success").show();
                    $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                }
                else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                   alert("Error occured !");
                }

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert('Please fill all the field !');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I have try to find on the Google, but can't find the solution for my case.

Comment: You only have one AJAX request and then a datepicker. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you show us how you put them in one page?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What do you mean by "it still get the result from first form"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add form id before the input element. 
Remember ids are always unique and can not be duplicate. So here I change id to class. Please check below code.

```
<div>
<form id="fupForm" name="form1" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control gp_name" id="" name="gp_name" 
value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control date" id="" name="date" value="<? 
php 
echo $deday;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control type" id="" name="type" 
value="Hotel">
</div>
<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" 
 value="Add Hotel" id="butsave">
</form></div>

<div>
<form id="fupForm2" name="form2" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control gp_name" id="" name="gp_name" 
value="<?php echo $gp_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control date" id="" name="date" value="<? 
php 
echo $deday;?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control type" id="" name="type" 
value="Coach">
</div>
<input type="button" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" 
 value="Add Coach" id="butsave2">
</form></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butsave').on('click', function() {
    $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var gp_name = $('#fupForm .gp_name').val();
    var date = $('#fupForm .date').val();
    var type = $('#fupForm .type').val();
    if(gp_name!="" && date!="" && type!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                gp_name: gp_name,
                date: date,
                type: type              
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                    $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
                    $("#success").show();
                    $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                }
                else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                   alert("Error occured !");
                }

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert('Please fill all the field !');
    }
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#butsave2').on('click', function() {
    $("#butsave2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var gp_name = $('#fupForm2 .gp_name').val();
    var date = $('#fupForm2 .date').val();
    var type = $('#fupForm2 .type').val();
    if(gp_name!="" && date!="" && type!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                gp_name: gp_name,
                date: date,
                type: type              
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(dataResult){
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                    $("#butsave2").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#fupForm2').find('input:text').val('');
                    $("#success").show();
                    $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                }
                else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                   alert("Error occured !");
                }

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert('Please fill all the field !');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. do you know how to shorten the code, so I could use one code to get multiple result? because both codes are similar, as you can see I only change the id.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` must be **unique** in a document. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

You get the same data each time, because you are searching using an id selector and error recovery means that you will always get the first one.

- Don't use IDs
- Do use selectors relative to the form you are dealing with

For example:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const $form = $(this);
  const $input = $form.find("[name=type]");
  console.log($input.val());
});
```

```css
form {
  padding: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type=hidden name=type value=foo>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<form>
  <input type=hidden name=type value=bar>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

The function [`$( document ).ready( function() {} )`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`$( function() {} )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) are equal. This will overwrite the previous variant. If you merge the code, it should work.

Comment: Binding multiple ready event handlers will run them in sequence, not overwrite previous ones. https://jsbin.com/meluqaluli/1/edit?html,js,console